# Why can't I get pstricks with auto-pst-pdf (and cropping) running on MikTeX?

Tags: pdftex, compiling, pstricks, miktex, ghostscript

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5.25,-5.25)(5.25,5.25)%
  \pscircle*[linecolor=cyan]{5}
  \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=lightgray,gridlabels=0pt]
  \Huge\sffamily\bfseries
  \rput(-4.5,4.5){A} \rput(4.5,4.5){B}
  \rput(-4.5,-4.5){C}\rput(4.5,-4.5){D}
  \rput(0,0){auto-pst-pdf}
  \rmfamily
  \rput(0,-3.8){PSTricks}
  \rput(0,3.8){\LaTeX}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

I run it with:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape Test.tex > log.txt 2>&1
```

But stdout says:

```
PDFCROP 1.33, 2012/02/01 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
!!! Error: Ghostscript exited with error code 1!
```

The same happens when using `\usepackage{pstricks} \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`.

If I use `\usepackage{pstricks} \usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}` then it works!

I use Windows 7 x64, MikTeX 2.9 x86 (complete system) with latest packages, installed latest ActivePerl x86 and also applied the [pdfcrop fix](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=14677) (as the related problem appeared earlier).

You see all details in the logs for [stdout](http://pastie.org/4684374), [Test.log](http://pastie.org/4684376), and [Test-autopp.log](http://pastie.org/4684379).

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I tried to manually run pdfcrop and got the same error. When I run it with --debug I see that it can't locate the Ghostscript executable `gswin32c.exe`. I looked into the MikTeX bin/ folder because I thought it is there, but it isn't. Do I have to install Ghostscript separately?

Comment: Maybe I should ask: How can I get more detailed error information than `!!! Error: Ghostscript exited with error code 1!`?

Comment: Use TeXLive and see what happens?

Comment: Ghostscript is not included in MikTeX.

Comment: @percusse: Why not? I mean, why include pdfcrop if it can't be used anyway? I always thought MikTeX is a complete solution.

Comment: Ghostscript has, as far as I know, license issues to be distributed freely. It's a standalone product and not a part of MikTeX family.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know why, but I had to separately install Ghostscript so that pdfcrop could use gswin32c.exe. I thought it was included (shouldn't it?) in MikTeX.

Another note: Although my minimal example is working now, I couldn't get it working for bigger documents. I figured out that there seems to be some (unwanted?) difference between

```
\usepackage{pstricks,auto-pst-pdf}
```

and

```
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
```

Only the first worked! For the second one I got strange Ghostscript errors:

```
Error: /typecheck in --div--
Operand stack:
   1   0   0.0   -0.0367123   a   65781.8
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1926   1   3   %oparray_pop   1925   1   3   %oparray_pop   1909   1   3   %oparray_pop   1803   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   4   --nostringval--   %repeat_continue   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1169/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:122/200(L)--   --dict:104/300(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 167839
```

Comment: You should ask your problem with `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` vs. `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` as a separate question, so it could potentially be seen by more people with a clue to answer.

Comment: write `\listfiles` into your preamble and then show the file list which is at the end of the log file.

Comment: @Herbert: Here you go: http://pastie.org/4694273

Comment: @neo: please create a minimal example with the article class which shows the problem. Then it is easier to see what's going wrong.

Comment: @Herbert: Alright, as Speravir already suggested I will create a new question for that issue when I got some time. I'll link it from here then.

Comment: @neo: ok. you can also try to run the document without using `auto-pst-pdf` but running it with `xelatex`

Comment: Created a new [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71189/using-pdfpstricks-with-beamer-doesnt-work-but-auto-pst-pdf-does-why) with minimal example, seems to be a problem with beamer.

Answer (score 0):

I made some test with miktex 2.9.: `auto-pst-pdf` with `pdfcrop` works for me only if an external `perl` is in the path. An external ghostscript is not necessary.  This here is the "minimal working path" (I guess the windows path is needed for `cmd.exe`):

```
Path=J:\MiKTeX2.9\miktex\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;J:\Perl\bin;
```

Comment: I already have Perl in my PATH, this was done automatically when installing ActivePerl.

Comment: @neo: And what else have you in your path? Is there another ghostscript? Does it work if you restrict the path to the entries I mentioned?

Comment: There's no other ghostscript in my path. I don't think it's a path problem anyway because the error says it exited with error code 1 which means that it actually run ghostscript. I will delete this question soon as it seems I get away with crop=off for my specific cases (using pstree).

Comment: Forget that. See my update! We're getting closer..