# PSTricks will not compile

Tags: color, pstricks

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=13.24in,margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\psset{unit=1in}
\begin{pspicture}(13.24in,9in)
\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=Maroon](0,0)(13.24,9)

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

I am following a tutorial outlined here: [How can I design a book cover?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17579/how-can-i-design-a-book-cover)

I am following the Robbers book.

Everything seems fine until I paste the `\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=Maroon](0,0)(13.24,9)`

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you are using `pdflatex` to compile. Somehow, `pstricks` is not friendly with `pdflatex`. To compile documents that use `pstricks`, you should use either `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`. To do so, you should run

```
xelatex yourtexfile.tex
```

from the command prompt. If you have an editor (which one you are using?), it will certianly have a button for this.

Or you may use the same `pdflatex` by adding `pdf` option to `pstricks`

```
\usepackage[svgnames,pdf]{pstricks}
```

But for this you should have the latest version of `pstricks`. The following code works for me with `pdflatex` (though I get 2 badboxes).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=13.24in,margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames,pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\psset{unit=1in}
\noindent
\begin{pspicture}(13.24in,9in)
\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=Maroon](0,0)(13.24,9)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need more help to know how to use `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` routes, please let us know with some details like which editor and tex distribution you are using.

## Edit:

You can make `xelatex` work with texmaker. First install a latest version of texmaker (make it a fresh install). Then pull the dropdown menu (by clicking the arrow tip next to pdflatex as in picture). Scroll down to get xelatex ans select it. Now you should get the button saying `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`.

[image]

[image]

Don't forget to remove `pdf` option from `pstricks` while using `xelatex`.

Comment: the `pdf` option doesn't work in all cases ...

Comment: @Harish Kumar I do get a pdf output running xelatex from the command line. However, I do not get any output in my editor using the pdflatex code you posted. I have run this code in both Gummi and Texmaker, with the same bad result. I am not sure how to invoke xetex from within these systems.

Comment: @Herbert True. But why? If `pstricks` works with `pdflatex` always and if the command names become less `alien`, I swear I will join `pstricks` gang  also `;-)`. It has lot of goodies which I like but you know ... My humble request with you is -- please do something to get `pstricks` work with `pdflatex` always.

Comment: @HarishKumar One [TeX.SX question example](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71193/15717) where `[pdf]` has problem. You might be aware of [PSTricks using pdflatex](http://youtu.be/bnz_yWKS1jo) at TUG 2010 and [Basics of PSTricks](http://river-valley.tv/media/video_tutorials/pstricks/E_Krishnan/) at http://river-valley.tv/ where TUG Proc videos are available

Comment: @HarishKumar: it needs an environment `pspicture` or `postscript` for the embedded PSTricks code. Then it will always work.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{pstricks}
```

to activate the color names. And don't forget the `\noindent`

```
[...]
\psset{unit=1in}\noindent
 \begin{pspicture}(13.24,9)     
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maroon is not a predefined color, you need to load the xcolor package with the dvipsnames option. Adding the following line underneath the `\usepackage[...]{geometry}` should make it work: `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}`.

This sample works for me:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=13.24in,margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\psset{unit=1in}
\begin{pspicture}(13.24in,9in)
\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=Maroon](0,0)(13.24,9)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Alternatively you can also add the svgnames/dvipsnames specification into the option of the documentclass, this will be passed on to the pstricks package, which will then hand it on to the xcolor package when it's loaded: `\documentclass[12pt,svgnames]{article}`

Comment: The above code does not work for me. Here is the output of the log file http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1530953/

Comment: use `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but how do I invoke xelatex? I have looked on the internet, but can not seem to find an answer.

Comment: which editor do you use?

Comment: I use Gummi or Texmaker. I tried the method on this page:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32020/use-xelatex-in-texmaker-instead-of-pdflatex but could not find XeLatex on the dropdown.

Comment: then you do not have installed GhostScript, right? I don't know, if MiKTeX has a package for it. Otherwise install it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/files/GPL%20Ghostscript/9.06/ After that you can add an output profile: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pdf/pdfoutput#TXC

Answer (score 0):

Texmaker works very fine with PStricks codes. Use the following packages in the preamble:

1. \usepackage{pstricks-add}
2. \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
3. \usepackage{pst-pdf}

Before you run the file using Quick Build (usually F1 button), go to the Texmaker Options-> Configure Texmaker-> Quick Build and change the quick build command to "Latex+dvips+ps2pdf+viewpdf".

[image: config]

Now you are done. Oh but there may be one more problem cropping up. Something like "Enable Write 18" or "shell escape disabled". You can sort out that problem by the beautiful answer given in this link:
[How can I enable write 18 on a MikTeX installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37489/how-can-i-enable-write-18-on-a-miktex-installation).

I am providing a sample tex file for drawing a simple graph:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\psscalebox{0.5 0.5} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
{
\begin{pspicture}(0,-2.195)(7.73,2.195)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dotsize=0.07055cm 6.0]{-*}(3.2,1.805)(1.2,-0.595)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dotsize=0.07055cm 6.0]{-*}(3.2,1.805)(2.4,-1.395)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dotsize=0.07055cm 6.0]{-*}(3.2,1.805)(4.0,-1.395)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dotsize=0.07055cm 6.0]{*-*}(3.2,1.805)(5.6,-0.195)
\rput{66.6232}(2.6010673,-3.5480006){\psarc[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, linestyle=dashed, dash=0.17638889cm 0.10583334cm, dimen=outer](4.0,0.205){1.6}{208.56584}{270.0}}
\rput[bl](3.6,1.805){\Huge{$u$}}
\rput[bl](0.0,-1.395){\Large{ 1($\beta$)}}
\rput[bl](2.0,-2.195){\Large{ 2($\beta$)}}
\rput[bl](4.0,-2.195){\Large{ 3($\beta$)}}
\rput[bl](6.0,-0.595){\Large{ $n-1(\beta)$}}
\end{pspicture}
}
\end{center}
\caption{Graph of type - I matrix}\label{t1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output in the pdf is :

[image: Figure generated by PStricks code]

Now, how to write these PStricks codes ?? Do we have to remember all the commands ?? No !! not at all !! Its very easy to generate these codes automatically by drawing the figures using Latex Draw. You can get this amazing free software at this link: http://latexdraw.sourceforge.net/

Thats all you need to know about using PStricks codes !!!