# Error when using `pst-circ`

Tags: pst-circ

The code is shown as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pst-circ}

\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](3,2)
      \pnodes(0,1){A}(3,1){B}
      \resistor(A)(B){$R$}
    \end{pspicture}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
```

and it shows "Undefined control sequence" at line 9 and 10.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Your code works fine for me, may the problem lies in version, please update with current setup and then try...

Comment: Well, I've tried this code in an online compiler and it didn't work...... and all of my local packages are the newest......

Comment: Ok, I've got a solution. [pdflatex not compatible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93754/pstricks-will-not-compile) So it is needed to switch to another TeX compiler. Such as xelatex.