# Miktex pdflatex no longer compiles pstricks commands

Tags: pdftex, pstricks, miktex

I have been using MikTex 2.9's pdflatex for several years with sample code similar to:

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
 \usepackage{pst-all}
 \begin{document}
 \psset{xunit=1cm}
 \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(4, 4)
 \psaxes{-}(0,0)(0,0)(4,4)[$x$,0][$y$,0]       
 \end{pspicture}
 \end{document}
```

That would generate a stand-alone PDF file that I would then bring into a main document with \includegraphics.

After a recent update (and then clean re-install) of MikTex 2.9 though, this code no longer compiles.  The compiling output is essentially identical to the original compiling that works, until these errors are triggered:

```
<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb>
<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
[1] 
Error: /typecheck in --div--
Operand stack:
   1   0   0.0   TeXcolorgray   65781.8
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1926   1   3   %oparray_pop   1925   1   3   %oparray_pop   1909   1   3   %oparray_pop   1803   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   5   --nostringval--   %repeat_continue   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1169/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:167/200(L)--   --dict:180/300(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 174298
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.

!!! Warning: Empty Bounding Box is returned by Ghostscript!
!!!   Page 1: 0 0 0 0
!!! Either there is a problem with the page or with Ghostscript.
!!! Recovery is tried by embedding the page in its original size.

==> 1 page written on `sample-pics.pdf'.
"-------------------------------------------------"
"auto-pst-pdf: End auxiliary LaTeX compilation"
"-------------------------------------------------"
```

and then later,

```
 (C:\Users\aableson\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
 [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
 )
 ! Undefined control sequence.
 <recently read> \c@lor@to@ps 

 l.7 \psaxes{-}(0,0)(0,0)(4,4)[$x$,0][$y$,0]

 ? OK, entering \batchmode
```

Summary: For over a year, MikTeX's pdflatex compiled the above file with no problems, and generated a usable PDF. 
Now, with a new install of MikTeX, pdflatex no longer compiles.  [File still compiles on a computer with an older installation]

Command used for both:
pdflatex --enable-write18 sample.tex

---

Any suggestions for what has changed and how to fix this would be welcome.  I would be open, under duress, to developing a new workflow with xetex or one of the other tools, but I would strongly prefer something that goes from emacs editing to a PDF in one step.  Thanks,

Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem for a few months. Something must have changed in `pstricks`. My solution was to remove the `pdf` option, and replace it with what the option does: loading `auto-pst-pdf` *after* pstricks.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard for the suggestion; I just came across the following comment on another post ([link]http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70664/why-cant-i-get-pstricks-with-auto-pst-pdf-and-cropping-running-on-miktex?rq=1[/link]).  They indicated \usepackage{pstricks,auto-pst-pdf}
**bold**, while my original \usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}  \usepackage[pdf]{pstricks} no longer does.  I changed to the one-line pstricks,auto-pst-pdf and everything seems to be back up and running.

Answer (score 1):

With the standalone class your example fails with another error due to a option clash with preview. With article I can reproduce your error and it is due to a bug in pstricks: There are too many braces and so it loads auto-pst-pdf in a group. One can demonstrate the problem with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
{\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}}
\usepackage{pst-all}

 \begin{document}
 \psset{xunit=1cm}
 \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(4, 4)
 \psaxes{-}(0,0)(0,0)(4,4)[$x$,0][$y$,0]
 \end{pspicture}
 \end{document}
```

You should make a bug report.

Comment: Thanks @ulrike-fischer: I'll try to follow up with a bug report to the MikTex group.

Comment: It is not a miktex bug, you should write the pstricks maintainer. I dropped him a mail.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike - I've never quite internalized the Byzantine relationships in the package/software hierarchy for TeX/LateX, so I appreciate you sending the bug report in the right direction. - Alan

Answer (score 0):

it makes no real sense to use documentclass `standalone` together with
package `auto-pst-pdf`. Both will run `latex`  in the background.
However, there are some special cases for loading `auto-pst-pdf` from
within `pstricks` which make things complecated. I created a new file
`pstricks-pdf` which makes it easier to load `auto-pst-pdf`. It should
be available for tomorrows update for TeXLive. Until the use:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
 \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
 \usepackage{pst-all}
 \begin{document}
 \psset{xunit=1cm}
 \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(4, 4)
 \psaxes(0,0)(0,0)(4,4)[$x$,0][$y$,0]       
 \end{pspicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't compile without error for me with standalone class, I get an option clash error for preview. `\documentclass[border=10pt,crop]{standalone}` seems to work.

Comment: do not use the `pstricks` option for `standalone`

Comment: `\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}` gives `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package preview.` too. One needs either the option `preview=false` or `crop` to avoid that standalone loads prewiev with other options than auto-pst-pdf. And only the option `crop` gives a "cropped" image.

Comment: I cannot see it with up-to-date TL and `pstricks-sty`  version 0.61 (CTAN)

Comment: I found the source of the problem: I had a local standalone.cfg in the test folder and it prevented the loading of the default cfg (which would set the crop option)